# Extract certain data from a text file and create a table

Tags: php, html, readfile

Hi I am very new on PHP programming i am just trying to learn a little bit more on how can i work with files.

I having a text file with some bunch of data like below.

[image from the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QyNu.png)

```
Policy Name:       TU_TOPS_VM-Full_30D_00_2
  Daily Windows:
         Saturday   19:50:00  -->  Sunday     06:00:00
Policy Name:       TU_QW_VM-FULL_30D_18_01
    Daily Windows:
          Sunday 02:05:00 --> Sunday 09:00:00
Policy Name:       TU_GPAS_FULL-VM_30D_18_01
    Daily Windows:
          Friday     22:00:00  -->  Saturday   06:00:00
```

I would like to have an output similar to this in a table.

```
POlicy                               Day              Time
TU_TOPS_VM-Full_30D_00_2 Saturday    Saturday         19:50:00
TU_QW_VM-FULL_30D_18_01              Sunday           02:05:00
TU_GPAS_FULL-VM_30D_18_01            Friday           22:00:00
```

---

From my code i was able to obtain the Policy name and organize the data in a table column.

Output from code.

```
POlicy                        Day     Time
TU_TOPS_VM-Full_30D_00_2
TU_QW_VM-FULL_30D_18_01
```

What i was able to do so far.

```
<?php
$lines= file('schedule');
$lines = preg_grep("/Policy Name:/", $lines);
echo'
<table>
<tr>
<td>POlicy</td>
<td>Day</td>
<td>Time</td>
</tr>';
foreach ($lines as $policy) {
$find="Policy Name:";
$replace="";
$po= (str_replace($find,$replace,$policy));
echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$po.'<br></td>
</tr>
</table>';
}
?>
```

How can i extract the day and time and organize it beside the policy 
    name?.

Comment: There are two day/time combos for each policy. Your example only provides for one day/time combo. Which one do you want to use, the one to the left of the arrow, or the one to the right of the arrow? Only the start one? Can you throw the end one away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're throwing away the other lines when you use `preg_grep`. Instead, loop over all the lines, checking which kind of line it is.

Also, `</table>` should not be inside the loop, it should only be at the end of the loop.

```
<?php
$lines= file('schedule', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE);
echo'
<table>
<tr>
<td>POlicy</td>
<td>Day</td>
<td>Time</td>
</tr>';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strstr($line, 'Policy Name:')) {
        $policy = str_replace('Policy Name:', '', $line);
    } elseif (preg_match('/(\w+)\s+(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s+-->/', $line, $match)) {
        $day = $match[1];
        $time = $match[2];
    echo "
<tr>
<td>$policy</td>
<td>$day</td>
<td>$time</td>
</tr>";
    }
}
echo "\n</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thanks a lot for your prompt answer, well looks like it works perfectly, i was trying to use yesterday the preg_match option but i did not understand very well .thanks a lot for your time, i will play a little bit with that code. And thanks for the advise with the table inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar wrote a great answer. Here's a different tack, in that I want to control where my array breaks (i.e. not at each line, because I'm not sure where your line breaks are). Also, less specific matching gives you more support for variability in your input (which may not be an issue for you).

```
<?php    
$string = file_get_contents('schedule') ; // read the file in as a string, not an array              
$text_array = explode("Policy Name:", $string) ; // break the string into an array of strings at each "Policy Name:"

foreach($text_array as $entry){
        $entry = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$entry) ; // conflate whitespace into a single space for delimiting
        $sub_entry_array = explode(' ', $entry) ; // split each substring into an array
        $table_rows .= "<tr><td>$sub_entry_array[1]</td><td>$sub_entry_array[4]</td><td>$sub_entry_array[5]</td></tr>" ; // display the array values we want
}

echo "<table><tr><th>Policy</th><th>Day</th><th>Time</th></tr>$table_rows</table>" ;
?>
```